# $ det(A).\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{det(Id+tA^{-1}X)- det(Id)}{t} =tr (A^{-1}X)$

Tags: linear-algebra

In some note it is written that $$ det(A).\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{det(Id+tA^{-1}X)- det(Id)}{t} =tr (A^{-1}X)$$

I could not understand how this is happen.
Can someone explain it in detail please.

Comment: Could you clarify your assumptions about $A$ and $X$. And I guess by $Id$ you mean identity matrix? And are you sure about the whole expression?

Comment: Let me put it this way. If $A$ and $X$ are arbitrary, pick $X=I$ and $A=\alpha I$. Then it is easy to see that the multiplication by determinant is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Define $f(t)$ as $\det(tB+I)$ where $B$ is assumed to be diagonalizable with diagonal elements, i.e. eigenvalues $\lambda_i$'s. Then the following identity holds:
$$
f(t)=\det(tB+I)=\prod_{i}(t\lambda_i+1).
$$
And the limit above turns into:
$$
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t}=f'(0)=\sum_i {\lambda_i}=\text{Tr}(B).
$$

---

More general solution:

It is well known that:
$$
f(t)=\det (tB + I) = 1 + t \text{Tr}(B) + \cdots + t^{n-1} \lambda(B) + \det(B) t^n.
$$
Now take the derivative and put $t=0$.

Answer (score 0):

A factor $\det A$ is missing on the RHS. A correct formula for the derivative of $\det$ is
$\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{tr}}$
$d_{A}(\det A):X\mapsto\det(A)\tr(A^{-1}X)$, from the definition of derivative, $[d_{A}(\det A)](X)=\left.\tfrac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\det(A+tX)$.